# How to add bootstrap-vue module Laravel Jetstream with InertiaJS?

Tags: laravel, inertiajs, laravel-jetstream

How can I work with bootstrap-vue on Laravel, using Laravel 8, Jetstream and InertiaJS?

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import { BootstrapVue, IconsPlugin } from 'bootstrap-vue'

// Import Bootstrap an BootstrapVue CSS files (order is important)
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'

// Make BootstrapVue available throughout your project
Vue.use(BootstrapVue)
// Optionally install the BootstrapVue icon components plugin
Vue.use(IconsPlugin)
```

I don't know where and how to add the app.js file.

app.js:

```js
require('./bootstrap');

// Import modules...
import { createApp, h } from 'vue';
import { App as InertiaApp, plugin as InertiaPlugin } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3';
import { InertiaProgress } from '@inertiajs/progress';

const el = document.getElementById('app');

createApp({
    render: () =>
        h(InertiaApp, {
            initialPage: JSON.parse(el.dataset.page),
            resolveComponent: (name) => require(`./Pages/${name}`).default, 
        }),
})
    .mixin({ methods: { route } })
    .use(InertiaPlugin)
    .mount(el);

InertiaProgress.init({ color: '#4B5563' });
```

This is my css.js.
Here add the CSS libraries.

```js
@import 'tailwindcss/base';
@import 'tailwindcss/components';
@import 'tailwindcss/utilities';

@import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
@import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css';
```

Answer (score 1):

As I can see from your configuration. You are using InertiaJS with Vue3. Right now, BootStrap-Vue components only works with Vue2 [(info)](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs). So you need first to downgrade InertiaJS from Vue3 to Vue2. With npm

```
npm uninstall @inertiajs/inertia-vue3 vue @vue/compiler-sfc vue-loader

npm install @inertiajs/inertia-vue vue vue-template-compiler vue-loader
```

It seems weird to uninstall and reinstall `vue` and `vue-loader`, but is the easiest way to properly update the dependencies.

Now you need to put in your `app.js`.

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import { createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue';
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue';

Vue.use(BootstrapVue);

createInertiaApp({
    resolve: (name) => require(`./Pages/${name}`),
    setup({ el, app, props }) {
        new Vue({
            render: (h) => h(app, props),
        }).$mount(el);
    }
});
```

The `app.css` does not need any modification. Unless you need to modify and theme Bootstrap, in that case you must change to SASS.